# Unable to add values to postgreSQL

Tags: php, postgresql

I'm working with php to add values read from a html web to a postgreSQL table, and I don't know why the value read doesn't add itself to the table. I'm working with pgAdminIV. Here is my code, hope someone could help me.

```
 <?php

  $mysqli=pg_connect("host=XXXXX.cim0cltex61z.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com port=5432 dbname=footplsseat user=footplsseat passsword=XXXXXXXX");
  $email= $_POST['email'];

  if (!$mysqli){
    echo "Connection failed";
  }
  else{
    echo "Succesfully connected";
  }

  $sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS testportal (
  id INT, 
  email char(50)
 )";

 $query = "INSERT INTO testportal (email) VALUES ('$email')";

?>
```

EDIT: change id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, for id integer.

Comment: `AUTO_INCREMENT` is not postgres shortcut

Comment: how do you run php in pgAdmin IV?..

Comment: I run it in wamp server, and I want to watch the result in the graphic interface

Comment: Those queries in PHP are not executed; you are only assigning values to some variables. You should give us example code that you expect to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem, I was mixing mySQL and postgresSQL code. Here is my solution:

```
<?php

$mysqli=pg_connect("host=XXXXX.cim0cltex61z.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com port=5432 dbname=footplsseat user=footplsseat password=XXXXXX");
$email = pg_escape_string($_POST['email']); 
$query = "INSERT INTO testportal(email) VALUES('" . $email . "')"; 
$result = pg_query($query); 
if (!$result) { 
    $errormessage = pg_last_error(); 
    echo "Error with query: " . $errormessage; 
    exit(); 
 } 
 printf ("These values were inserted into the database - %s", $email); 
 pg_close(); 

?>
```